# Translating/transposing an Iphone app to Android

Tags: java, iphone, android, objective-c

My team and I are within days of finishing our first iphone app.  However, we went to program the same app onto android.  None of us have any experience with android.  I've been reading up on some tutorials for android beginners.

Since I know there are many knowledgable and experienced android/iphone programers on stackoverflow, i was wondering if there are any tips/resources you guys could shoot my way.

thanks!

Comment: Learn Java, learn Eclipse, learn Android API. Sorry for the terseness but your questions implies no-Java experience. In the likelihood you have serious Objective-C and iOS experience your app won't necessarily turn out the way you want using something like Titanium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the best experience (for your users), you really ought to learn how to develop on Android using the standard Android tool chain. Applications shouldn't just be 'translated' from platform to platform, they really should be redesigned.

There are differences between platforms that really require rethinking of how things should work, both at the user level and at the code level. Simply translating between platforms results in a poor experience for the result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your project is structured out or what technology you use. Anyway, for me, I implemented all the logics and coding in C++ other than the interface itself. Then, I used JNI for the C++ code on Android. At the end of the day, it's a matter of building Java GUI programming on Android.

Alternatively, you could use some portable framework like Titanium and PhoneGap. But they do need some learning curves and you might experience weird behaviors.

Comment: I'm just confused on where to place all my files.  For example, I have classes that don't have their own specific interface.  They basically just make objects which interact with the view controllers.  do these classes go under services?  I know that activities have their own screen, and none of those classes have their own screen.